# Pebble: Android App to Pebble App

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I am working on sending JSON from an android app in my phone to my pebble but I am unable to do so!

which layers should I used for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send JSON directly to a layer but you can use AppSync to easily synchronize some values between the Android app and the Pebble app. You will need to use `TextLayer` to display the information and update their content every time the AppSync dictionary is updated.

You should look into [AppSync documentation](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/guides/app-phone-communication.html) and also the [weather example on Android](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/tree/master/weather-demo).